# Google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu gives a network error on Centos

Tags: google-chrome, centos-7, headless

Running google-chrome-browser latest (75) is giving me a really strange error I am unable to decipher, and I can't find anything helpful about this:

```
$ google-chrome --disable-gpu --headless 'http://google.com'
[0612/131933.198197:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(221)] Waited 4 ms for network service
```

Using both that and stable changed nothing. The network call is anything between 2 and 6 ms, but what is the problem?

Comment: The below link doesn't help me either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403638/errorbrowser-process-sub-thread-cc221-waited-57-ms-for-network-service-with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the workaround to be `--disable-features=NetworkService`. I'm not sure how well this will work, but it gets rid of the error.

Comment: Seems to work here, too. Context: Ruby RSpec tests with Chromium, Capybara & headless_chromium driver.